# How to resolve this docker error when running wolkenkit start on Windows 10

Tags: docker, wolkenkit

When I run `wolkenkit start` on a Windows machine, the command fails and I get the following output:

```sh
Starting the application...
  Validating the application code...
  Verifying health on environment default...
  Verifying application status...
  Verifying that ports are available...
  Setting up network...
  Building Docker images...
  Starting Docker containers...
✗ Failed to start the application.
  docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint boards-postgres (7cf3e33d876e8d22fced3926fdc9ddf2372b499803dc92a4b7bb403fd2552064): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3030:tcp:172.21.0.4:5432: input/output error.

  ExecutableFailed: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint boards-postgres (7cf3e33d876e8d22fced3926fdc9ddf2372b499803dc92a4b7bb403fd2552064): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3030:tcp:172.21.0.4:5432: input/output error.

    at childProcess.exec (C:\Users\wagle\Dev\tnw\wolkenkit\src\shell\exec.js:21:20)
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
```

I'm running on Windows 10 using Docker Desktop for Windows 2.0.0.3. Any ideas where this problem might originate from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we (at the native web, the company behind wolkenkit), ran into this problem as well.

It's actually a problem caused by one of the latest updates for Windows 10. This updated introduced a new feature called "Fast startup" which causes problems for Docker.

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277

As a quick fix, you can restart Docker. As a more long term solution, you can disable the "Fast Startup" feature, see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/953#issuecomment-342498223

Hope this helps

PS: Please note that I am one of the core developers of wolkenkit.